# JPA Spring repository findAll() returns an empty List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to fetch all the records using JPA findAll. If I run the same query in the terminal, I get some rows as a result, but not through JPA. I tried other answers on stackoverflow, but nothing worked. I tried adding public getters and setters, although which I assume was done by the annotations.

Model class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "tea")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "prod_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "prod_seq", sequenceName = "seq_prod", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "price_per_kg")
    private int pricePerKg;
    private String type;
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;
    private String category;

}
```

Service class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.tea.exceptions.ProductNotFoundException;
import com.tea.models.Product;
import com.tea.repository.ProductRepository;
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService{
    
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() throws ProductNotFoundException {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding the repository code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.tea.models.Product;



public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer >{
    
    @Query("from Product where type like :type ")
    List<Product> findByType( String type);

    
    @Query("from Product where type =?2  and category= ?1")
    List<Product> findByCategoryAndType(String category, String type);


    @Query("from Product where category like :category")
    List<Product> findByCategory(String category);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add this prop 'spring.jpa.show-sql=true' within your application properties and post the query it actualley performs to retrieve your data?
Also a look into the Repository interface itself would help

Comment: Could you please share the ProductRepository code? It could be that you've overridden the findAll() method by writing native query or something else.

Comment: when is ProductNotFoundException thrown?

Comment: @ShaikhHafizAhamed Sorry for the delay. I've added the repository code. Can you please take a look. The SQL query generated from findAll() prints expected result (all rows) when copy pasted in SQL terminal

Comment: Are you sure your application is connected to the same database as your SQL terminal is connected to? How are you setting those settings?

Comment: Looks like you are messing up the table names. You have `@Table(name = "tea")` on your entity but your custom queries use `Product` as table name. Maybe you are also using the `Product` table in your sql terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I think query should contain alias name for table like Product p and then condition like p.type.